# Jolt Transform extracting data from flattened array into object

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am having some trouble with extracting data from a flattened array. I'm flattening a JSON file then using Jolt I am preparing the data.

Having this structure:

```json
{
  "body.places[0]_name": "Test",
  "body.places[0]_population": "72",
  "body.places[1]_name": "Demo",
  "body.places[1]_population": "182"
}
```

I am trying to get to:

```json
{
  "place_test": "72"
  "place_demo": "182"
}
```

Has anyone got any ideas on making this work?

Comment: If you want to use jq anyway, it'd be easier if you wouldn't flatten it in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, however this part comes after the flatten message in my pipeline, and I want to keep things streamlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate two different individual arrays representing ***name*** and ***population*** values in the first **shift** transformation respectively. Then match those elements depending on their ordinality within the arrays in the second transformation spec, and prefix the keys with **Place_** in the last spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "body.places\\[*\\]_n*": "n",
      "body.places\\[*\\]_p*": "p"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "p": {
        "*": "@(2,n[&])"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "Place_&"
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

PS : *this looks like a **Jolt** question except for the **jq** tag*

Answer (score 0):

With your unflattened input, this could have been a one-liner. Here, we have to unflatten it first.

```sh
jq '
  to_entries
  | reduce (
      group_by((.key / "_")[0])[]
      | map(.key |= (. / "_")[1])
      | from_entries
    ) as $g (
      {};
      .["place_\($g.name | ascii_downcase)"] = $g.population
    )
'
```

```json
{
  "place_test": "72",
  "place_demo": "182"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/rWXQTORabu)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
{ place_test: .["body.places[0]_population"],
  place_demo: .["body.places[1]_population"] }
```

Or if that trailing comma must be dealt with:

```
hjson -j | jq ...
```